# Why do we use the name 'x' in the tensorflow-serving example?

Tags: mnist, tensorflow-serving

I'm reading the basic tutorial of tensorflow serving. From mnist_saved_model.py I can't uderstand something:

```
serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='tf_example')
feature_configs = {'x': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[784], dtype=tf.float32),}
tf_example = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_configs)
```

I don't understand why we use the name 'x' in feature_configs.

Answer (score 0):

It's using a linear equation, where convention has it that y as the output and x as the input.

`y = x * w + b`

- x = input
- w = weights
- b = bias
- y = output

Comment: But the key "x" was supposed to be in the serialized_tf_example like here [tf.parse_example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_example)